# Defining a surjective predicate for maps and functions

Tags: dafny

I'm running into a few problems defining a surjective predicate for maps and functions.

```
predicate isTotal<G(!new), B(!new)>(f:G -> B)
    reads f.reads;
{
     forall g:G :: f.requires(g)
}

predicate Surjective<A(!new), B(!new)>(f: A -> B) 
    requires isTotal(f)
{
    forall b: B :: exists a: A :: f(a) == b 
}

predicate isTotalMap<G(!new), B(!new)>(m:map<G,B>)
{
     forall g:G :: g in m
}

predicate mapSurjective<U(!new), V(!new)>(m: map<U,V>)
    requires forall u: U :: u in m.Keys
{
    forall x: V :: exists a: U :: m[a] == x
}
```

These definitions seems to work somewhat. However, they fail to verify the following setups.

```
datatype Color = Blue | Yellow | Green | Red

function toRed(x: Color): Color {
    Red
}

function shiftColor(x: Color): Color {
    match x {
        case Red => Blue
        case Blue => Yellow
        case Yellow => Green
        case Green => Red
    }
}

lemma TestSurjective() {
    assert isTotal(toRed);
    assert isTotal(shiftColor);
    var toRedm := map[Red := Red, Blue := Red, Yellow := Red, Green := Red];
    var toShiftm := map[Red := Blue, Blue := Yellow, Yellow := Green, Green := Red];
    // assert Surjective(toRed); //should fail
    // assert Surjective(shiftColor); //should succeed
    // assert mapSurjective(toRedm); //should fail
    // assert forall u: Color :: u in toShiftm.Keys;
    assert isTotalMap(toShiftm); //also fails
    assume forall u: Color :: u in toShiftm.Keys;
    assert mapSurjective(toShiftm); // should succeed
}
```

1. I assume the reason the maps fail the totality requirement defined in mapSurjective is because that the maps are potentially heap objects and Dafny isn't bothering to keep track of what is in them? Even if I assume the precondition the predicate still fails even though it should pass.
2. For the function case `assert Surjective(shiftColor)` also fails. For types with infinite cardinality I could understand it failing, but I feel like it should be possible to evaluate for finite types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, let me clarify how you can improve and prove your code.

```
// Note: to be useful, the function's type should be --> (a broken arrow)
// indicating the function CAN have preconditions.
// Otherwise, -> is already a subset type of --> whose constraint is exactly your predicate
// so it would be a typing issue to provide a non-total function.
// See https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-arrow-subset-types
predicate isTotal<G(!new), B(!new)>(f:G --> B)
//    reads f.reads   // You don't need this, because f is not declared as being able to read a function
{
    forall g:G :: f.requires(g)
}

// Passthrough identity function used for triggers
function Id<T>(t: T): T { t }

predicate Surjective<A(!new), B(!new)>(f: A -> B) 
{
    // If not using Id(b), the first forall does not have a trigger
    // and get hard to prove. Not impossible, but extremely lengthy
    forall b: B :: exists a: A :: f(a) == Id(b)
}

predicate isTotalMap<G(!new), B(!new)>(m:map<G,B>)
{
     forall g: G :: g in m
}

predicate mapSurjective<U(!new), V(!new)>(m: map<U,V>)
    requires forall u: U :: u in m.Keys
{
    // If not using Id(b), the first forall does not have a trigger
    // and get hard to prove. Not impossible, but extremely lengthy
    forall x: V :: exists a: U :: m[a] == Id(x)
}

datatype Color = Blue | Yellow | Green | Red

function toRed(x: Color): Color {
    Red
}

function shiftColor(x: Color): Color {
    match x {
        case Red => Blue
        case Blue => Yellow
        case Yellow => Green
        case Green => Red
    }
}
function partialFunction(x: Color): Color
  requires x.Red? {
  x
}

lemma TestWrong() {
  // When trying to prove an assertion with a proof, use assert ... by like this:
  assert !isTotal(partialFunction) by {
    // If we were using ->, we would get "Value does not satisfies Color -> Color"*
    // But here we can just exhibit a counter-example that disproves the forall 
    assert !partialFunction.requires(Blue);

    // A longer proof could be done by contradiction like this:
    if(isTotal(partialFunction)) {
      assert forall c: Color :: partialFunction.requires(c);
      assert partialFunction.requires(Blue); // it can instantiate the forall above.
      assert false; // We get a contradiction
    }
    assert !isTotal(partialFunction);// A ==> false means !A
  }
}

lemma TestSurjective() {
    assert isTotal(toRed);
    assert isTotal(shiftColor);
    var toRedm := map[Red := Red, Blue := Red, Yellow := Red, Green := Red];
    var toShiftm := map[Red := Blue, Blue := Yellow, Yellow := Green, Green := Red];
    assert !Surjective(toRed) by {
      if(Surjective(toRed)) {
        var _ := Id(Blue);
      }
    }
    assert Surjective(shiftColor) by {
      if(!Surjective(shiftColor)) {
        var _ := Id(Blue); // We need to trigger the condition of surjective so that Dafny is happy with the below:
        assert !forall b: Color :: exists a: Color :: shiftColor(a) == Id(b);
        assert exists b: Color :: forall a: Color :: shiftColor(a) != Id(b);
        var b : Color :| forall a: Color :: shiftColor(a) != Id(b);
        assert shiftColor(shiftColor(shiftColor(shiftColor(b)))) == Id(b);
        assert false;
      }
    }
    assert forall c: Color :: c in toRedm by {
      if(!forall c :: c in toRedm) {
        assert exists c :: c !in toRedm;
        var c :| c !in toRedm;
        assert c != Red;// Dafny picks up from here
        assert false;
      }
    }
    assert !mapSurjective(toRedm) by {
      if(mapSurjective(toRedm)) {
        assert forall x :: exists a :: toRedm[a] == Id(x);
        var _ := Id(Blue); // Will instantiate the axiom above with x == Blue
        assert exists a :: toRedm[a] == Id(Blue); // Not needed, but Dafny can prove this.
        assert false;
      }
    }
    assert forall u: Color :: u in toShiftm.Keys by {
      if(!forall u: Color :: u in toShiftm.Keys) {
        assert exists u :: u !in toShiftm.Keys;
        var u :| u !in toShiftm.Keys;
        assert u != Red; // Dafny can pick up from here
        assert false;
      }
    }
    assert isTotalMap(toShiftm); //also fails
    assert forall u: Color :: u in toShiftm.Keys;
    assert mapSurjective(toShiftm) by {
      if(!mapSurjective(toShiftm)) {
        var _ := Id(Red); // Necessary so that Dafny understands that the next forall is equivalent
        assert !forall x :: exists a :: toShiftm[a] == Id(x);
        assert exists x :: forall a :: toShiftm[a] != Id(x);
        var x :| forall a :: toShiftm[a] != Id(x);
        assert forall b :: exists a :: toShiftm[a] == Id(b) by {
          forall b: Color ensures exists a :: toShiftm[a] == Id(b) {
            var a := toShiftm[toShiftm[toShiftm[b]]];
            assert toShiftm[toShiftm[toShiftm[toShiftm[b]]]] == Id(b);
          }
        }
        assert exists a :: toShiftm[a] == Id(x);
        var b :| toShiftm[b] == Id(x);
        assert false;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, this is a real master class answer. The Id trick is really clever. I can see how that would work immediately. It's feel both obvious and crazy that that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the following. For maps, I defined these two lemmas.

```
lemma TotalColorMapIsTotal<B>(m: map<Color, B>) 
    requires m.Keys == {Red, Blue, Green, Yellow}
    // ensures forall u: Color :: u in m
    ensures isTotalMap(m)
{
    forall u: Color | true
        ensures u in m
    {
        if u.Red? {
            assert u in m;
        }
    }
}

lemma ColorMapIsOnto<A>(m: map<A, Color>) 
    requires m.Values == {Red, Blue, Green, Yellow}
    ensures forall u: Color :: u in m.Values
{

    forall u: Color | true
        ensures u in m.Values
    {
        if u.Red? {
            assert u in m.Values;
        }
    }
}
```

Which with some assertions, when applied to the example total and surjective map verified.

```
    assert toShiftm[Red] == Blue;
    assert toShiftm[Blue] == Yellow;
    assert toShiftm[Yellow] == Green;
    assert toShiftm[Green] == Red;

    TotalColorMapIsTotal(toShiftm);
    ColorMapIsOnto(toShiftm);
    assert mapSurjective(toShiftm);
```

and when I supplied the following assertions for the function version also verified.

```
    assert shiftColor(Green) == Red;
    assert shiftColor(Red) == Blue;
    assert shiftColor(Blue) == Yellow;
    assert shiftColor(Yellow) == Green;
    assert Surjective(shiftColor); //should succeed
```

So I guess they work, but feels a bit underpowered. Is this the best that can be done?

Comment: I think this is ! Great job finding the lemmas. The IDE tells me that some of your forall statements don't have triggers, you should add passtrhough identity function that can act like that. Also, you don't need the isTotal predicate. Dafny does not believe maps are stored in the heap because they are immutable.

Comment: Could you give an example of the passthrough identity function?

If maps are immutable then reason that we must separately assert the contents just another extensionality situation?